# How to export animation to Unity

Tags: animation, export, unity

Hi I've animated a simple mesh using the AnimAll addons, now I would like to export the animation (packed into fbx or not, it's not important) to Unity 5. How can I do that ? I've already tried to export the animation doing File->Export-> Fbx then import the fbx into unity but the animation is missing.
From the other hand I got 2 different meshes:

1) Is the mesh of the model at frame 1.
2) Is the mesh of the model at frame 80. ( the frame where I've put the animation).

Answer (score -1):

just drag and drop the blend file into unity assets folder, and open the file, then drag the armature to controller. thats all...